# C++11 providing empty non-member function when it is missing

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In my serialization system, I can provide non-member functions that implement how to serialize given types:

```
// struct foo
struct foo {
    int bar;
};

// serialize foo
template <class stream> void serialize(stream& s, foo& f) {
    stream.serialize(f.bar);
}
```

If I wanted to provide an empty `serialize` implementation when a non-member function `serialize` does not exist for a given type, how can I achieve that using C++11?

I tried this

```
template <class stream, class type> void serialize(stream&, type&) {}

// struct foo
struct foo {
    int bar;
};

// serialize foo
template <class stream> void serialize(stream& s, foo& f) {
    stream.serialize(f.bar);
}

// ...later in source file:
foo f;
stream s;
serialize(s, f);
```

but it always calls the empty method somehow.

Comment: How does silently failing (doing nothing) make a good plan for when someone doesn't describe how to serialize themselves?  I ask this because we might be misunderstanding what you actually want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a non-member function template.

```
template <typename stream, typename T> void serialize(stream& s, T& t) {}
```

Here's a demonstrative program:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename stream, typename type> void serialize(stream&, type&)
{
   std::cout << "Came to 1\n";
}

struct stream
{
   void serialize(int ) {}
};

// struct foo
struct foo {
    int bar;
};

// serialize foo
template <class stream> void serialize(stream& s, foo& f) {
   std::cout << "Came to 2\n";
   s.serialize(f.bar);
}

struct bar {
};

int main()
{
   // ...later in source file:
   foo f;
   stream s;
   serialize(s, f);
   bar b;
   serialize(s, b);
}
```

and its output under cygwin/g++ 6.4.0:

```
Came to 2
Came to 1
```

It works at [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/XII5ym) too.

Comment: When I do that, it just always end up calling this empty function, even thought I provide implementation for some types. Could declaration order be an issue?

Comment: @Deathicon, I added a bit more content to the answer.

Comment: Ok I don't know what's going on on my side, its not working for some reason... I'll have to dig it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: My issue was caused by namespaces. Sorry for the noise.